# Upgrading to Windows 10 -- Need to change motherboard?

Tags: windows, drivers, motherboard, windows-10

My current motherboard ([Asus P8Z77-V LE PLUS](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V_LE_PLUS/)) does not have any Windows 10 drivers listed on the official site. Does this mean I will have substandard performance on my machine if I upgrade to Windows 10 and have to make do with generic drivers?

I remember this is how things used to be, but I'm hopeful that in this day and age it's no longer a problem.

Comment: Windows 10 just came out, they probably haven't updated it yet. Also, it looks like some of the files are the same across different versions anyways. Just make sure your other hardware is supported by Windows 10.

Comment: @MC10 Microsoft give hardware manufacturers months to write driver software. That's one of the reasons they have Beta builds. I don't think there's going to be a driver update now, unfortunately.

Comment: I guess that's the case then, unfortunately. Would it be that much worse without specific drivers?

Comment: @MC10 That's what I'm asking X^D